# want to update JSON using N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to update couchbase json. look at first JSON

```
{
  "_id": 4,
  "_type": "Company",
  "balance": "0",
  "companyTypes": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "transactions":{
      "amount": "120",
      "method": 2,
      "transactionType": "4"
    }
}
```

I want to update

1. companyTypes as 1,3
2. transactions-> method=3

How can I do this using **N1QL** ??

Comment: Tried anything yet? Like seeing what the UPDATE command does? http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html

Comment: I can not understand it @cricket_007

Comment: Hi, are you using Couchbase 4.5? If so, open the Query Workbench or cbq shell, and play around with the UPDATE command as @cricket_007 said. Similar to SQL: UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...;

Comment: yes I can do this. But I want to update inside json of json. i have no idea about it. in main json I can do as you said. @geraldss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will address your specific question. You can generalize the pattern.

Note that this is all documented in the link from @cricket_007.

```
UPDATE mybucket
SET companyTypes = [1, 3],
    transactions.method = 3
WHERE ...;
```

Comment: companyTypes = [1, 3] it working fine but  transactions.method = 3 this is not working

Comment: Can you edit your post and add an exact document from your data, and your exact query.

Comment: can you see this question ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838443/want-to-sum-inner-element-with-json-in-using-n1qlcouchbase