# want to sum inner element with JSON in using N1QLCouchbase

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

when I run below query

```
SELECT * FROM myBucket WHERE ANY x IN transactions SATISFIES x.type in [0,4] END;
```

Result:

```
{
  "_type": "Company",
  "created": "2015-12-01T18:30:00.000Z",
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": "96.5",
      "date": "2016-01-03T18:30:00.000Z",
      "type": 0
    },
    {
      "amount": "483.7",
      "date": "2016-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
      "type": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I get multiple json like this

```
SELECT sum(transactions[*].amount) FROM Inheritx WHERE ANY x IN transactions SATISFIES x.type in [0,4] END;
```

Result:
[
{
    "$1": null
 }
]

**Now** I want to sum of all this. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transactions[*].amount this is return array so first need to user array function

```
ARRAY_SUM
```

than use sum like below.

```
SELECT sum(ARRAY_SUM(transactions[*].amount)) FROM Inheritx WHERE ANY x IN transactions SATISFIES x.type in [0,4] END;
```